# "Run command extension execution is in progress. Please wait for completion before invoking a run command"

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have created a VM. Associated it with NSG, I want to activate ssh in that VM.
I'm able to run a command only once in azure shell, Next time when I try to run a command I'm getting **"Run command extension execution is in progress. Please wait for completion before invoking a run command"**.

How to resolve this??

Comment: First, if you create the Linux VM with Azure image, the ssh is opened as default. So you just open 22 port in NSG associated.

Second, if you run an extension before, you must wait until the extension finished. Then you can run the next extension. In Azure, you can just run only one extension at one time.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT Hello Charles, is there some way to see which process is running this? and if it would be possible to manually kill it? Because I'm also getting the same exception and despite stopping and starting the VM, I keep getting this. Any help or suggestions?

Comment: You can see the extension status in the Azure portal -> VM overview -> Extension, if you really want to stop or remove the extension, you can uninstall the extension in that panel until the task finished. And then restart the VM. By the way, the ssh service is opened by default when you create the Azure Linux VM.